# ArcGIS - Export - Security

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

We use an ArcSDE 10 database. We would like to **log all events to export data** (ArcObject) in ArcGIS Desktop 10.

Do you have an idea? a sample (ArcObject)?

Answer (score 2):

You might try using [IApplication.LockCustomization](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/LockCustomization_Method/00230000003q000000/) and pass it a class that you've written that implement ICustomizationFilter.

I think when the user right clicks on a featurelayer (or standalone table) and chooses Data>Export it will call [ICustomzationFilter.OnCustomizationEvent](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/OnCustomizationEvent_Method/0023000000n7000000/), passing `esriCEInvokeCommand`.  You should be able to cast eventCtx to ICommandItem and see what command was invoked.  If it is the data export command you can log that somewhere.

I'm not sure how to determine if they actually click OK on the export dialog (and not cancel).

Comment: There are many other ways remain to perform export data like VBA code, geoprocessing tools, python console, 3rd party addins.

Comment: Perfect. I catch the export function with my extension but with geoprocessing tool, it's very complex to catch this.:(